# Swagger-ui blank white screen (Spring Boot - Swagger)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

When I integrate Swagger into spring project, Swagger blank page comes up.
When I try to reach Swagger with the following url, a blank page comes up.
http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>
```

**main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8081
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
```

**Security class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the default ? Remove

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
```

and access

`http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html`

Comment: I tried before.